# Connection to OpenID Config File Fails because of SSL Issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, ssl, ssl-certificate, openid-connect

I have a .Net 6 app that runs on Azure.  For OIDC SSO I need to pull the ".well-known/openid-configuration" file.  Using HTTPClient I can get the file when running my app on local host.  But, when it runs on Azure,  I get an error that says "The SSL Connection could not be established.  The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain".  I dont have much experience with SSL Certs.  Is the issue on my end (in my app or in Azure) or an issue with the external Identity Provider that hosts the openid-configuration file? The code is as follows:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var url = "https://someSite.com/oidc/my.client.id/.well-known/openid-configuration";
try{
   using(var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    var response = client.GetAsync(url).GetAwaiter().GetResults();
    if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
      //log success
    }
  }
}Catch(Exception ex){
   //log Error
   LogMyError(ex);
}
```

How can I determine where the issue resides?  In other words, is the issue in Azure?  Or how my application is setup?  Or in the environment where  the Azure resides?  Any tips on how to narrow down the issue would be helfpul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have public SSL certificate problems, you can test it using the SSL [Server Test tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/) from SSLLabs.